# color schema of emacs auto-complete mode

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, jedi

[image]

I am using auto-complete + jedi in python mode

And i am wandering how to change the color of the second column in the popup menu? 
the yellow one: "function:posix.closerange"

also what't yellow popup window on the right side called? And how to change its color?

i found these confing, but they are not what i want

```
(set-face-background 'ac-candidate-face "white")
(set-face-foreground 'ac-candidate-face "black")
;(set-face-underline  'ac-candidate-face "blue")

;(set-face-background 'ac-selection-face "cornflowerblue")
(set-face-foreground 'ac-completion-face "purple")
;(set-face-background 'ac-completion-face "green")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not auto-complete faces but "popup faces".

The first face you are looking for is `popup-summary-face`

The second face (the one with the yellow background) you are looking to change is `popup-tip-face`

Just do a `M-x customize-face RET popup-summary-face,popup-tip-face` and you can play with them.